# Add users to multiple database / SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, authentication

I have to add users to multiple database in only one script

The login was created so i only need mapped the users to his respective database and give him datareader permissions.

I think that my only problem is how select and use the database because i only can assign permission for one database (step by step)

This is my code  (I know that after i gotta execute)

```
SELECT 
  'USE [' + name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  + 'create user [sd-reader] for login [sd-reader]' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  + 'EXEC sp_addrolemember  ''db_datareader'', ''sd-reader'''

FROM sys.databases

WHERE database_id > 7;
```

The databases that i need are between 8 and 12 id

Comment: `'[' + value + ']'` isn't a safe way to quote. Use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: This just looks like a bad idea. Can you provide some more details as to why you are doing it this way as there is likely a better way to do what you are after.

Comment: Because i have so many database, so i can't do it manual. This is the reason so i would like do it automatic with a script.
In this case, i only have 4 database to assign but in other case i have 98 o more

Answer (score 0):

Set the result to text mode and run the query

```
;With Results as 
(
SELECT database_id as id, cast(
    'USE [' + name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  + 'create user [sd-reader] for login [sd-reader]' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  + 'EXEC sp_addrolemember  ''db_datareader'', ''sd-reader''' as nvarchar(max))  as qry
  FROM sys.databases 
  where database_id = 1

  Union all

    SELECT database_id as id, cast ( 
        ('USE [' + name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
      + 'create user [sd-reader] for login [sd-reader]' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
      + 'EXEC sp_addrolemember  ''db_datareader'', ''sd-reader''' +  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + + CHAR(10) + Results.qry )  as nvarchar(max)) as qry
       FROM sys.databases join Results on (Results.id + 1 = sys.databases.database_id)
  where sys.databases.database_id > 1


) 
select top 1 qry from Results
order by id desc
```